# How to manage site quotas

Tags: document-library, quota, information-policy

What's the best approach / process to advise users of when discussing how to keep their document libraries and sites within their site quotas? (OnPrem instance)

Answer (score 1):

it is little very much open ended question. When user asked us about the quota increase, here what i do

- If versionning enabled then limit it( i forced them for max 4 version)
- delete the unused data(documents, sites etc)
- Empty the recycle-bin.
- if they are using SharePoint as storage place you may force them to different tools(if you company has)
- Ask them why they need more storage.